# Is there a migration document from Luwak to the new Lucene version?

Tags: java, lucene

I was looking into reverse indexing and found "Luwak". The problem is that in Lucene 8.2.0's release, Luwak was merged into Lucene and transformed to a "Monitor" class. So, the original repository is no longer maintained. A piece of basic usage code is mentioned in the original repo's [readme](https://github.com/flaxsearch/luwak):

```
Monitor monitor = new Monitor(new LuceneQueryParser("field"), new TermFilteredPresearcher());

MonitorQuery mq = new MonitorQuery("query1", "field:text");
List<QueryError> errors = monitor.update(mq);

// match one document at a time
InputDocument doc = InputDocument.builder("doc1")
                        .addField(textfield, document, new StandardAnalyzer())
                        .build();
Matches<QueryMatch> matches = monitor.match(doc, SimpleMatcher.FACTORY);

// or match a batch of documents
Matches<QueryMatch> matches = monitor.match(DocumentBatch.of(listOfDocuments), SimpleMatcher.FACTORY);
```

but no such "Basic usage" code is available for the Lucene version.

One of the major committers of Luwak, Alan Woodward mentioned [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-8766?focusedCommentId=16826961&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16826961) that

> I'll add a migration document to the luwak repository to help people moving from the standalone project to the lucene version.

But no such document could be found, as confirmed by a user [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-8766?focusedCommentId=17006390&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17006390)

So, how could one start using the "Lucene embedded Luwak version" or the `Monitor` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_8_0/monitor/index.html) for the `Monitor` class and this is the code that I came up with to replicate the "Basic usage" code present in the Luwak repository's Readme.

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("content", analyzer);

Monitor monitor = new Monitor(analyzer);

MonitorQuery mq = new MonitorQuery("query1", parser.parse("content:test"));
monitor.register(mq);
    

Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new TextField("content", "This is a test document", Field.Store.YES));

MatchingQueries<QueryMatch> matches = monitor.match(doc, QueryMatch.SIMPLE_MATCHER);
```

Some points to be noted are as follows:

1. `Monitor`'s constructor takes the `Analyzer` instead of the `LuceneQueryParser`. And if the `Presearcher` is not mentioned then the "default term-filtering Presearcher" is used.
2. Instead of `update`, `Monitor` has the `register` method with a `void` return type.
3. Instead of `InputDocument` used in Luwak, `Monitor` uses the inbuilt `Document` class of Lucene.
4. The `MatcherFactory` argument passed in the `match` method could be found through this `QueryMatch.SIMPLE_MATCHER`.

PS: If someone wants to work with Luwak but is struggling with the docs, this is a good place to start with. However, could this act as a part of the "migration document"? Only *@romseygeek* (Alan Woodward) could tell xD.